# How to access a kubernetes service in GCP by name from a vm?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, hostname

I have a load balancing kubernetes service hosted in gcp called myService in the namespace myNamespace.  I've given it a tag of 'myKubeTag'.  I also have a vm running which itself is running a docker container that wants to communicate with the myService.  I've created a firewall rule to allow tcp traffic between the two.

I can give the IP address of the service to the vm to connect, what I'm wondering is, how do I set up a name proxy, so that the vm can just reference it by name?

The workload and service are launched from helm, and look like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: {{ template "app.prefix" . }}
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: {{ template "app.prefix" . }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: {{ template "app.prefix" . }}
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        target_workload: {{ .Values.prefix }}-myApp
      containers:
        - name: myApp
          image: {{ .Values.myApp.image }}
      tolerations:
        - key: "target_workload"
          operator: "Equal"
          value: {{ .Values.prefix }}-myApp
          effect: "NoSchedule"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ template "app.prefix" . }}
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    role: {{ template "app.prefix" . }}
```

I've ready the following:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

which makes me think that the host name would be myService.myNamespace.sxc.cluster-domain.myCluster, however the container running on my VM is throwing an Unknown host exception.

Comment: Can you clarify if it is already working using just IP address (assuming the GKE cluster is set up using IP Aliases)? It would be helpful to show the example of it working so we have some more context.

Comment: How did you setup the LB?

Comment: @AndyShinn I've updated it to contain the manifests for the workload and service.  They're very standard.  I can request the cluster IP from the service, and get back a valid IP.  What I'm wondering is, from the perspective of a vm running in the same project, what would a valid hostname be to access the same service?

Comment: I was basically wondering if you set up Alias IP per https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips. But I didn't want to just give this link as an answer so I was trying to give a better example of this using private cloud DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Once you use Service `type: LoadBalancer` inside [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/) it automatically assigns you an ExternalIP:

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.12.0.1      <none>         443/TCP        162m
nginx-svc    LoadBalancer   10.12.15.100   35.232.130.5   80:30826/TCP   8m27s
```

In this example domains looks like the following `5.130.232.35.bc.googleusercontent.com`

I've checked that by doing a `nslookup` from inside the nginx pod

```
$ kubectl exec nginx-deployment-85c9bf4fd7-h5tt9 nslookup 35.232.130.5
Server:         10.12.0.10
Address:        10.12.0.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
5.130.232.35.in-addr.arpa       name = 5.130.232.35.bc.googleusercontent.com.
```

Keep in mind there is no nslookup inside default `nginx` image so you will need to install it.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for.  The issue is that the service comes up and down, and it won't necessarily have the same IP address each time.  The VM that I want to reference it from is long lived, so I don't want to have to keep updating the IP.  It'd be better if I could just give it a static hostname, and the VM can communicate with it when something exists there.

Comment: @Andy, you can have a look at [Access service from outside Kubernetes cluster](https://gardener.cloud/050-tutorials/content/howto/service-access/). But this only exposes the `Service` inside the cluster.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm still lost here.  It does show that load balancers have an external IP, but that is still a generated value?

Comment: This is not a static IP, it's being generated each time you apply `Service`. You might use [Automatic DNS for Kubernetes Ingresses with ExternalDNS](https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/automatic-dns-kubernetes-ingresses-externaldns/).